# How to combine two or more lists by adding each element

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have lists that contain only integers like `[1,2,3]` and `[4,5,6]`. Some times I even have `[7,8,9]` or more lists. How do I add each elements together to form a new list of the same length?

```
[1,2,3] + [4,5,6] + [7,8,9] = [12,15,18]
```

I know that the above would just append the elements and create a longer list (with 9 elements), but instead I would like to add the lists element-wise.

Comment: Does a list always have 3 elements?

Comment: How do you determine if there's another list? What's the limit on number of lists?

Comment: Put all the lists in another list, then apply `zip` to it and apply `sum` to the result.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The list have four elements. There is an "ID" as the first element. I need to find all the lists with the same "ID" value. Normally if there are two or three with the same ID value.

Answer (score 5):

You can put the lists in a list, `zip` the sub-lists after unpacking them with the `*` operator, and `map` the `sum` to a list:

```
l = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
print(list(map(sum, zip(*l))))
```

This outputs:

```
[12, 15, 18]
```

Edit: The above is for Python 3.x. If you're using an earlier version, you can use `itertools.izip` instead of `zip`, and you would not need to call the `list` constructor:

```
import itertools
l = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
print map(sum, itertools.izip(*l))
```

Comment: Your first solution works perfectly even in python2.7, only except the "print()"... thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help. You're right that the latest revision of Python 2.7 does support `zip` as a built-in function. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Numpy is well suited for this task, although it might be slight overkill for your case.

Let's say you have

x = [1,2,3]
  y = [4,5,6]
  z = [7,8,9]

You can turn them into an array and sum across them:

```
np.array([x, y, z]).sum(axis=0)
```

You could use a similar approach with regular lists and `zip`:

```
[sum(col) for col in zip(x, y, z)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it like this:**

```
#Create the list
x = [1,2,3,12,13]
y = [4,5,7,11]
z = [7,8,9,14,15,16]
#create a list with the list length
lenList = [len(x),len(y),len(z)]

finalList = []
#get the minimum and maximum list length
minLen = min(lenList)
maxLen = max(lenList)
#if the three list have the same length then you can simply sum the element
if(maxLen == minLen):
    for j in range(maxLen):
        finalList.append(x[j]+y[j]+z[j])
else:
    #if the list have different length look for the minimum value
    while(lenList[0] != lenList[1] or lenList[0] != lenList[2]):
        minLen = min(lenList)
        maxLen = max(lenList)
        #if the min len is the x list then add some zero
        if(lenList.index(minLen) == 0):
            #change the len to the max len
            lenList[0] = maxLen
            for a in range(minLen,maxLen):
                x.append(0)
        #if the min len is the y list then add some zero
        elif(lenList.index(minLen) == 1):
            lenList[1] = maxLen
            for b in range(minLen,maxLen):
                y.append(0)
        #if the min len is the z list then add some zero
        elif(lenList.index(minLen) == 2):
            lenList[2] = maxLen
            for c in range(minLen,maxLen):
                z.append(0)
    #sum all the element
    for j in range(0,maxLen):
        finalList.append(x[j]+y[j]+z[j])

print finalList
```

**output:**

```
[12, 15, 19, 37, 28, 16]
```

**Comments:**

This program can sum all the list element and insert the result in another list. You can sum 3 list, with infinite element and without having the same list length. If you need to sum more list just edit this part:

```
while(lenList[0] != lenList[1] or lenList[0] != lenList[2]):
        minLen = min(lenList)
        maxLen = max(lenList)
        #if the min len is the x list then add some zero
        if(lenList.index(minLen) == 0):
            #change the len to the max len
            lenList[0] = maxLen
            for a in range(minLen,maxLen):
                x.append(0)
        #if the min len is the y list then add some zero
        elif(lenList.index(minLen) == 1):
            lenList[1] = maxLen
            for b in range(minLen,maxLen):
                y.append(0)
        #if the min len is the z list then add some zero
        elif(lenList.index(minLen) == 2):
            lenList[2] = maxLen
            for c in range(minLen,maxLen):
                z.append(0)
```

Here you can add:

```
elif(lenList.index(minLen) == 3):
            lenList[3] = maxLen
            for c in range(minLen,maxLen):
                listN.append(0)
```

After that you have to add the list:

```
#Create the list
x = [1,2,3,12,13]
y = [4,5,7,11]
z = [7,8,9,14,15,16]
listN = [0,0,0]
#create a list with the list length
lenList = [len(x),len(y),len(z),len(listN)]
```

And in the sum iteration you have to change:

```
#sum all the element
    for j in range(0,maxLen):
        finalList.append(x[j]+y[j]+z[j],listN[j])
```

Answer (score 0):

an alternative method if you know the length of the sub lists are 3

```
a = [1,2,3] + [4,5,6] + [7,8,9]
[sum([a[3*q+i] for q in range(len(a)//3)]) for i in range(len(a)//3)]
```

**output**

```
[12,15,18]
```

**alternatively**

```
dicta = {q:i for q,i in enumerate(a)}
[sum([dicta[3*q+i] for q in range(len(a)//3)]) for i in range(len(a)//3)]
```

you can just swap the 3's out with what ever length you use, but since you showed in your code that they where already laid to gether, i wouldn't be able to read it automaticly. What goes for the alternative solution, then dictionaries uses hashes so if your list gets big it won't be a problem.